# Using Clover PHP and Checkstyle in Jenkinsfile

Tags: php, jenkins

Inside my Freestyle Jenkins job I can add the Post-build actions to generate a code coverage report using the plugin [Clover PHP](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clover+PHP+Plugin) and an analysis using [Checkstyle](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Checkstyle+Plugin) plugin.

However, I like to use the Pipeline Jenkins job, because it has the stage view. With the Pipeline job I need to set up everything inside a Jenkinsfile. How do I include the Clover PHP and Checkstyle plugin function inside a Jenkinsfile? There is no documentation on their page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both the things you want to integrate with have CLI interfaces, you can just call their CLIs using an `sh` action in the `Jenkinsfile` to call a shell command.  Here's an example from the Clover PHP docs:

```
sh "phpunit --log-junit 'reports/unitreport.xml' --coverage-html 'reports/coverage' --coverage-clover 'reports/coverage/coverage.xml' test/"
```

The location for the Junit log will vary depending on where you put in your project. You must run a `junit` step before this runs.

Checkstyle [also has a CLI](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html) that you can call in a similar way from an `sh` action in your `Jenkinsfile`.

As long as you archive the resulting HTML files with your build, you can read the resulting HTML files by navigating to them through the "Build Artifacts" link on the build page. An example URL structure might look like:

```
https://ci.example.com/job/develop/342/artifact/reports/coverage/index.html
```

For deeper integration, the tools may need explicit Jenkins Pipeline support.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I understand the commands and will place them in my Jenkinsfile. What I do not understand is, how will the Jenkins job read the generated reports? In the freestyle job I can point the plugin to the generated files, see [image](http://i.imgur.com/NOSuYHY.png).

Answer (score 4):

To complete other answers, Clover PHP dont have jenkins pipeline support... But you dont need this plugin, all you need is the [Clover Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Clover+Plugin)

One installed, then all you have to add in your jenkinsfile for your example, is:

```
step([
$class: 'CloverPublisher',
cloverReportDir: 'reports/coverage',
cloverReportFileName: 'coverage.xml',
healthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 70, conditionalCoverage: 80, statementCoverage: 80],
unhealthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 50, conditionalCoverage: 50, statementCoverage: 50],
failingTarget: [methodCoverage: 0, conditionalCoverage: 0, statementCoverage: 0]])
```

This what I use in my current project.

Answer (score 3):

After much tinkering I managed to run Checkstyle on pipeline like this:

```
stage ('Static code analysis') {
    sh "sudo phpcs --config-set ignore_warnings_on_exit 1 --report=checkstyle --report-file=checkstyle-result.xml -q /code"
    step([$class: 'hudson.plugins.checkstyle.CheckStylePublisher', pattern: 'checkstyle-*'])
}
```

The first step generates the report and the second calls the Checkstyle plugin to process the report. I have not used Clover PHP so can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

The [snippet generator](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/31/pipeline-snippetizer/) from Jenkins is a great resource for this.

Unfortunately, there's no native support for Clover PHP, but there is for Checkstyle:

```
checkstyle canRunOnFailed: true, defaultEncoding: '', healthy: '', pattern: 'build/logs/checkstyle.xml', unHealthy: ''
```